# can opencv templateMatch support size not matched template?

Tags: android, opencv

I am using openCV to recognize an icon from different density devices, the icon display in different size for different density of devices.
If the template size is the same as the icon displayed in screencapture, it can find the right position, but if not, it can not find the right position, even totally wrong.
So, I want to know can opencv templateMatch support size not matched template?

here is my code:

```
    imgPath = "/sdcard/screencapture.png";
    Mat img = getMatFromFile(imgPath);
    Mat templ = null;
    try {
        templ = getMatFromInputStream(getAssets().open("home_big.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "templ.type()="+templ.type());
    Log.i(TAG, "img.type()="+img.type());
    Log.i(TAG, "templ.depth()="+templ.depth());
    Log.i(TAG, "img.depth()="+img.depth());

    Mat result = new Mat();
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, Imgproc.TM_CCORR_NORMED);

    MinMaxLocResult minMaxLocResult = Core.minMaxLoc(result, new Mat());
    Point matchLoc = minMaxLocResult.maxLoc;
    Log.i(TAG, "match result="+matchLoc);
    Log.i(TAG, "maxVal ="+minMaxLocResult.maxVal);
```

I also tried feature detect, I print the matched points, and refer the x,y of both the image and the template, but look at the result, the match.distance = 0 match point, which means feature equals, the x,y is not in the matching area, I can not rely on this to find out the right position of the template in the image. Can any body help on this?
Here is my code:
    In fact I tried to use feature detection, but the result make me confuse, Here is my code:

```
    imgPath = "/sdcard/screencapture_htc.png";
    Mat img = getMatFromFile(imgPath, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat templ = null;
    try {
        templ = getMatFromInputStream(getAssets().open("icon.png"), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
    DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.BRIEF);
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_L1);


    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img, keypoints1);
    detector.detect(templ, keypoints2);

    List<KeyPoint> keypoints1List = keypoints1.toList();
    List<KeyPoint> keypoints2List = keypoints2.toList();

    extractor.compute( img, keypoints1, descriptors1 );  
    extractor.compute( templ, keypoints2, descriptors2); 

    MatOfDMatch matches= new MatOfDMatch();  
    matcher.match( descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);  

    Log.i(TAG, "matches.size() = "+matches.size());
    Log.i(TAG, "matches.toArray() = "+matches.toArray());

    List<DMatch> matchList = matches.toList();

    if(matchList != null){
        matchList =  filterGoodMatch(matchList);

        MatchComparator matchComparator = new MatchComparator();
        Collections.sort(matchList, matchComparator);

        int goodMatchCount = matchList.size();
        List<DMatch> goodMatchList = matchList.subList(0, goodMatchCount >    MAX ? MAX - 1 : goodMatchCount - 1);

        Log.i(TAG, "match result:");
        Log.i(TAG, "**************************");
        for(DMatch match:goodMatchList){
            Log.i(TAG, "match.distance = "+match.distance);
            Log.i(TAG, "img point = "+keypoints1List.get(match.queryIdx));
            Log.i(TAG, "train point = "+keypoints2List.get(match.trainIdx));
            Log.i(TAG, "**************************");
        }
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "no match");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Template matching does just that, it looks for "pixel-over-pixel" correlations. It cannot handle scale changes.

If you have differently scaled images, you should either re-scale your image or you template.

If there are just a few possible scales, you can keep multiple pre-scaled templates and use the right one for each case, or just try them all and just the best match.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, any good idea to achive this? I also tried FeatureDetector, but still can't get good result. I need to find out the right positon on the target image.

Comment: As I said, *"If there are just a few possible scales, you can keep multiple pre-scaled templates and use the right one for each case, or just try them all and just the best match."*

Answer (score 0):

If the scale or orientation of your template can vary then `matchTemplate` will fail. `matchTemplate` is the simplest and weakest method in opencv for detecting objects in scenes.
I think you see about topics of feature detection, description and matching. It think the followings will be a good starting points for you:

- [Feature Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection)
- [Feature Description](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_description/feature_description.html#feature-description)
- [Feature Matching with FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher)
- [Homography to find a known object](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried feature detect, but confused, could you see my updates?